# find nth position of a specific character in a string in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am running Postgres 9.6

I have a list of various class codes.
Here is:

'What I have' And 'What I Want'

what I have --> what I want.

```
Equip:Mold         --> Equip:Mold
Raw:Resin:TPA      --> Raw:Resin 
FG                 --> FG
...
```

My strategy to accomplish this is to write a user defined function that will find the character count  2nd ':' in my list then use the `LEFT` function with a `LEFT('Raw:Resin:TPA',nthpositionget('Raw:Resin:TPA',':',2))`

I tried using the following question to no avail.
[Postgres: extract text up to the Nth Character in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981863/postgres-extract-text-up-to-the-nth-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This overall problem is best handled with `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace('Raw:Resin:TPA', '(^.*:.*):', '\1');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 Raw:ResinTPA
(1 row)

select regexp_replace('Equip:Mold', '(^.*:.*):', '\1');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 Equip:Mold
(1 row)

select regexp_replace('FG', '(^.*:.*):', '\1');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 FG
(1 row)
```

If you want something that finds the nth occurrence of a substring, then something like this could be made into a function:

```
with invar as (
  select 'Raw:Resin:TPA' as a, ':' as d
)
select case
         when length(array_to_string((string_to_array(a, d))[1:2], d)) = length(a) then -1
         else length(array_to_string((string_to_array(a, d))[1:2], d)) + 1
       end
 from invar;
```

Comment: Thanks, what you gave me worked. I created the following user defined function. https://gist.github.com/danielleevandenbosch/d80cb274c5d61e0c25fe62e3b9984c23