# Extract text up to the n-th character in a string, but return the whole string if the character isn't present

Tags: regex, postgresql

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981863/postgres-extract-text-up-to-the-nth-character-in-a-string) and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47981949/470530) gives this as a solution for the case when there are fewer than n characters in the string:

```
^(([^>]*>){4}|.*)
```

However, I have done a [fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=590086c1b009d83a8d6fb4c1909df208), and it shows that this regex will just simply return the entire string all of the time.

This code:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(a FROM '^(([^>]*>){4}|.*)'),
  a,
  LENGTH(SUBSTRING(a FROM '^(([^>]*>){4}|.*)')),
  LENGTH(a),

  LENGTH(SUBSTRING(a FROM '^(([^>]*>){4}|.*)')) = LENGTH(a)
  
FROM s
WHERE   LENGTH(SUBSTRING(a FROM '^(([^>]*>){4}|.*)')) = LENGTH(a) IS false;
```

after several runs returns no records - meaning that the regex is doing nothing.

### Question:

I would like a regex which returns up to the fourth `>` character (not including it) **OR** the entire string if the string only contains 3 or fewer `>` characters. [`RTRIM()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-trim-function/) can always be used to trim the final `>` if not including it is too tricky - having an answer which gives both possibilities would help me to deepen my understanding of regexes!

This is **not** a duplicate - it's certainly related, but I'd like to correct the error in the  original answer - and provide a correct answer of my own.

Comment: An alternative solution without a regex: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=21ede6b762854e40952648841a06484f

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thanks for your input, but the original question contains a [simpler version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65266216/470530) of this which works very well - if there are fewer than 4 `>`s, it includes the whole string. I have used CARDINALITY in the past and it can be very handy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(a, '^((?:[^>]*>){4}).*', '\1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PqHFlI/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `((?:[^>]*>){4})`  - Group 1 (`\1`): four sequences of any chars other than `>` and then a `>` char
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

Here is a test:

```sql
CREATE TABLE s
(
  a TEXT
);
INSERT INTO s VALUES 
('afsad>adfsaf>asfasf>afasdX>asdffs>asfdf>'),
('23433>433453>4>4559>455>3433>'),
('adfd>adafs>afadsf>');
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(a, '^((?:[^>]*>){4}).*', '\1') as Output FROM s;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your input. I don't want to replace the last `>` - I want to `SELECT` the string - as per [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=441449b6b9939a815656531d856de01e) (not really important - your regex works) - I'd just like to know how to include the final (4th) `>` character if I so wished?

Comment: @Vérace It is there in the final output. If you want to *exclude* it, you would use `'^((?:[^>]*>){3}[^<]*).*'`

Comment: Not quite. It will include the final `>` if there are fewer than 4 `>`s - but if there are 4 `>`s, the regex removes it. I'd just like to know how to **keep** the final (4th) `>` if I wanted to? It would help me understand the subtleties of regexes. I'll be marking your answer as correct anyway, because you made the effort to explain it - I'd  just appreciate the little extra snippet I've asked for?

Comment: @Vérace I think you ask about `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(a, '^((?:[^>]*>){3}[^>]*).*', '\1') as output FROM s;`, right? See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=97f8ac38f2867eb1a7f7c1c7299d07f3).

Comment: In the fiddle, in the first record, say I want to keep the `>` after the X?

Comment: @Vérace It is already there, the `>` after `X` is not removed, see the demo in my answer.

Comment: I don't understand. If I run `SELECT SUBSTRING(a, '^((?:[^>]*>){3}[^>]*).*') as Output FROM s;` I get `afsad>adfsaf>asfasf>afasdX` - I want `afsad>adfsaf>asfasf>afasdX>` - note `>` at end! See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4d930f89d7992312c60d7ba4457fd6d4) - hope this is now clear? It's the cherry on the icing! :-)

Comment: @Vérace `SUBSTRING` *extracts* the match. `REGEXP_REPLACE` *replaces* the found match(es) with replacement pattern. So, you'd just need `SUBSTRING(a, '^(?:[^>]*>){4}')` as 1) you are extracting, and 2) you need to match the fourth `>`.

Comment: Correct - I see what you've done. Thanks for your input and patience on this! I wanted to extract - not replace! BTW, it should be {0,4} or else strings with fewer than 4 `>` s come up as NULL with SUBSTRING!

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat matching 0-3 times including the `>` using

```
^(?:[^>]*>){0,3}[^>]*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[^>]*>){0,3}` Repeat 0 - 3 times matching any character except `>` and then match `>`
- `[^>]*` Optionally match any char except `>`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eRsx7Q/1).

If there should be at least a single `>` then the quantifier can be `{1,3}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you care to explain the regex? Also, how would I modify it to include the final (i.e. 4th) `>` character?

Comment: @Vérace You could include the 4th `>` character repeating the first part 0 - 4 times like `^(?:[^>]*>){0,4}` If the `>` is optional at the end `^(?:[^>\n]*>){0,3}[^>\n]*>?`