# How to withdraw the substring that follow a pattern in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

I need to find a pattern which will give me a substring which follows logic to substring from the right side, after the third `_`.

What I want to achieve is to retrieve everything up until 3rd `_` .

I tried this SQL, but it did not work

```
select 
    SUBSTRING('22D_XYZ_xy_100_xyz_123', 1, position('_' in REVERSE('22D_XYZ_xy_100_xyz_123')) - 1) as result;
```

It returns the `22D` whereas I expect `22D_XYZ_xy`

Comment: And what should be returned?

Comment: Everything until the third substring.

Comment: Só you expect 22D_XYZ_xy? Please add all needed information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract text up to the Nth character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981863/extract-text-up-to-the-nth-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Added all relevant info.

Comment: Please look at the link, there are some solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase, "substring which follows logic to substring from the right side, after the third `_`," is difficult to understand. I infer that the intended behavior is to extract the subtring that includes all text before the third `_` from the right and not all text before the third `_` from the left. When searching from the left, there is also ambiguity as to expected behavior if there are less than three `_` characters: should the entire string be returned  or should the result be `NULL`? Unfortunately, the example input, `22D_XYZ_xy_100_xyz_123`, and expected output, `22D_XYZ_xy`, are consistent with all of these cases. The following query demonstrates all three interpretations:

```
SELECT
  string,
  regexp_substr(string, '^.*(?=(_[^_]*){3}$)') as from_right,
  regexp_substr(string, '^([^_]*_){0,2}[^_]*') as from_left,
  regexp_substr(string, '^([^_]*_){2}[^_]*(?=_)') as from_left_requires_3
FROM (
  VALUES ('22D_XYZ_xy_100_xyz_123'),
         ('1_2_3_4_5_6_7'),
         ('1_2_3_4_5_6'),
         ('1_2_3_4_5_'),
         ('_1_2_3_4_5'),
         ('1_2_3_4_5'),
         ('1_2_3_4'),
         ('1_2_3'),
         ('1_2_'),
         ('1_2'),
         ('1'),
         ('____'),
         ('___'),
         ('__'),
         ('_'),
         (''),
         (NULL)) t(string);
```

Executing the query gives the following:

| string | from_right | from_left | from_left_requires_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '22D_XYZ_xy_100_xyz_123' | '22D_XYZ_xy' | '22D_XYZ_xy' | '22D_XYZ_xy' |
| '1_2_3_4_5_6_7' | '1_2_3_4' | '1_2_3' | '1_2_3' |
| '1_2_3_4_5_6' | '1_2_3' | '1_2_3' | '1_2_3' |
| '1_2_3_4_5_' | '1_2_3' | '1_2_3' | '1_2_3' |
| '_1_2_3_4_5' | '_1_2' | '_1_2' | '_1_2' |
| '1_2_3_4_5' | '1_2' | '1_2_3' | '1_2_3' |
| '1_2_3_4' | '1' | '1_2_3' | '1_2_3' |
| '1_2_3' | NULL | '1_2_3' | NULL |
| '1_2_' | NULL | '1_2_' | NULL |
| '1_2' | NULL | '1_2' | NULL |
| '1' | NULL | '1' | NULL |
| '____' | '_' | '__' | '__' |
| '___' | '' | '__' | '__' |
| '__' | NULL | '__' | NULL |
| '_' | NULL | '_' | NULL |
| '' | NULL | '' | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

To search from the right, a positive lookahead zero-length assertion, `(?=(_[^_]*){3}$)`, is used to check that the unmatched portion of the string begins with `_` and includes exactly three `_` characters. If the assertion is false, then `NULL` is returned.

To find the left substring with no more than two `_` characters, the regular expression matches up to two substings of zero or more non-`_` characters followed by a single `_` along with any non-`_` characters prior to the next `_` or the end of the string.

Finding the left substring preceding a required third `_` is similar to finding the left substring with no more than two `_` characters, except that the occurrence specifier for the group is `{2}` instead of `{0,2}` and a positive lookahead zero-lengh assertion, `(?=_)`, ensures that `_` is the first unmatched character. As with the search from the right, if the assertion is false, then NULL is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('22D_XYZ_xy_100_xyz_123', '^[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+') as result;
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/AyzToRbf)